# Armature Deformations different while rendering

Tags: rigging, armature

I have a character rigged, and the character is in a scene.  I pose the armature in the view port in solid view. I check it in rendered view in cycles. Everything is good, the character is sitting on a couch. Everything seems good.

When I render an image, however, the rotations are exagerated, and the legs are bent up to the characters chin (nearly 180 degrees) when they appeared at about 90 degrees in preview.

[image: Pig rig deformation problem]

Comment: Try pressing 'i' with the armature selected, and then select 'Visual LocRotScale'a from the menu. Do this for the armature and the pig, should fix your issue.

Comment: There are no keyframes to begin with.  Doing this for the armature does nothing.  Doing it on the pig's mesh makes the pig's mesh jump away from the armature....  Which I didn't expect, but I suppose makes sense.   Long story short, that isn't it, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you share your blend so someone can see what is happening? [blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) is the preferred method, then add the link to your question.